# Is it possible to do the Reader Monad from Haskell in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, monads, reader-monad

I've had a look at the [algo.monads](https://github.com/clojure/algo.monads/wiki) and [fluokitten](http://fluokitten.uncomplicate.org/articles/functors_applicatives_monads_in_pictures.html) documentation. I've also read through monad blog entries by [Jim Duey](http://www.intensivesystems.net/tutorials/monads_101.html), [Konrad Hinsen](http://onclojure.com/2009/03/05/a-monad-tutorial-for-clojure-programmers-part-1/) and [Leonardo Borges](http://www.leonardoborges.com/writings/2012/11/30/monads-in-small-bites-part-i-functors/).

The only reference I can find to the Reader Monad in Clojure is [this google groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/fRx8TnWrNiA/-8Drz8VmrdQJ).

My question is: **Is it possible to do the [Reader Monad from Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html) in Clojure?** Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure. A `Reader` is just a function that takes an environment and extracts some value from it.

With `Reader`, `m-result` takes some value and produces a reader that ignores the environment and returns that value:

```
(defn reader-result
  [value]
  "Ignores environment, returns value"
  (fn [env]
    value))
```

`m-bind` takes a reader and a function `f` that accepts a value and produces a new reader. It then combines those arguments to produce a new reader which applies the initial reader to an environment, feeds the value it produces to `f` to produce a new reader, then applies that reader to the environment:

```
(defn reader-bind
  [reader f]
  "Applies reader to environment,
   then applies f to new environment"
  (fn [env]
    (let [read-value (reader env)]
      ((f read-value) env))))
```

With these functions, we can define `Reader` with `algo.monads`:

```
(m/defmonad Reader
          [m-result  reader-result
           m-bind    reader-bind])
```

There are a few important helper functions. `run-reader` takes a reader and environment and applies the reader to that environment:

```
(defn run-reader
  "Runs a reader against an environment,
   returns the resulting environment"
  [reader env]
  (reader env))
```

Since our readers are just functions, `run-reader` isn't strictly necessary. However, it can make things clearer and it keeps us closer to the Haskell implementation, so we'll use it going ahead.

`ask` and `asks` let us examine the environment. `ask` is a reader that returns the environment. `asks` takes a selector and creates a reader that applies that selector to an environment:

```
(defn ask
  "A reader that returns the environment"
  [env]
  env)

(defn asks
  "A reader that returns the result of
   f applied to the environment"
  [f]
  (fn [env]
    (f env)))
```

This gets us far enough to go through the [first `Reader` example](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#1):

```
(defn lookup-var
  [name bindings]
  (get bindings name))

(def calc-is-count-correct?
  (m/domonad Reader
             [binding-count    (asks #(lookup-var "count" %))
              bindings         ask]
             (= binding-count (count bindings))))

(defn is-count-correct?
  [bindings]
  (run-reader calc-is-count-correct? bindings))

(def sample-bindings {"count" 3, "1" 1, "b" 2})

(println
    (str "Count is correct for bindings " sample-bindings ": "
         (is-count-correct? sample-bindings)))
```

The other important `Reader` function is `local`. This takes a function that modifies an environment and a reader and creates a new reader that modifies the environment before passing it to the original reader:

```
(defn local
  [modify reader]
  "A reader that modifies the environment
   before calling the original reader"
  (fn [env]
    (run-reader reader (modify env))))
```

With that, we can go through the [second example](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#2):

```
(def calc-content-len
  (m/domonad Reader
             [content ask]
             (count content)))

(def calc-modified-content-len
  (local #(str "Prefix " %) calc-content-len))

(let [s "12345"
      modified-len  (run-reader calc-modified-content-len s)
      len           (run-reader calc-content-len s)]
  (println
    (str "Modified 's' length: " modified-len))
  (println
    (str "Original 's' length: " len)))
```

So, that's all it takes to make `Reader`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some fantastic examples of the following monads [in Clojure here](https://github.com/bwo/morph/blob/master/src/test/clojure/blancas/morph/test_monads.clj):

- the reader monad in clojure
- the writer monad in clojure
- the state monad in clojure
- the identity monad in clojure
- the maybe monad in clojure
- the either monad in clojure